# I want to change my OS X ruby version to 1.9 without using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

yeah, you heard me right! I want to nix RVM for the time being and just run off of a system-level installation of Ruby 1.9.3

In other words, I want to just upgrade the old 1.8.7 version of ruby that came with my Mountain Lion installation to 1.9.3.

How would i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upgrade to ruby 1.9.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546573/how-to-upgrade-to-ruby-1-9-2)

Comment: The question is, why would you want to do this? The whole point of RVM is not to mess with your operating system's environment, because, as far as I know, messing with the system ruby on OS X is not such a good idea (sorry, no source, can't remember where I read that ;)

Comment: You don't want to do that.  The OS install uses the Ruby in /usr/bin for system functions, so you should leave it alone.  You can certainly install Ruby 1.9 without RVM, but use Fink or MacPorts or just compile it yourself, but install someplace other than /usr/bin.

Comment: Don't mess with the Ruby that Apple installed. They put it there for their convenience, not yours. Install a Ruby into /usr/local or continue to use RVM or RBENV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it with homebrew

```
$ brew install ruby
```

But I don't really think that it's a good idea. RVM is perfect tool for managing ruby installations and gemsets.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

Even if you installed ruby manually or via homebrew, you can simply symlink it into rbenv and it will just work (TM):

```
cd ~/.rbenv/versions
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125 1.9.3-p125
rbenv rehash
```

That's because rbenv doesn't modify things like the shebang line. It does only what it needs to and doesn't do any funny business with your shell.